# Trying to insert custom 404 CSS on Wordpress but losing site header

Tags: wordpress, function

I am trying to load a custom CSS file for just my 404 page in my child theme's `header.php`.  I am able do that by checking for 404 status with the built-in WP function, and when the condition is true, insert link to the file.  For some reason though, the site header (including navigation menu) disappears. Any suggestions to get both the header to display and use the 404 function? Code for linking to the file is below.

```
 <head>
  <?php
   if ( is_404() ) 
   {
    echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/wp-content/themes/theretailer-child/404style.css">';
   }
  ?>
  <?php wp_head(); ?>
 </head>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add Your CSS file the Wordpress Way:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_custom_css');
function my_custom_css()
  {
    if(is_404())
      {
        wp_enqueue_style('custom-404-css', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/custom-404-css.css');
      }
  }
```

This code should be placed in your functions.php on your theme.

Comment: Perfect.  That kept the code out of the `header.php` file which is where I seem to keep running into the breakage.  Thank you very much.

Comment: You're Welcome :)